# Android Camera Preview is corrupting image output on G2?

Tags: android, android-camera, commonsware

I'm using Android's `Camera` and `SurfaceView` to show a the preview image to the user before taking a picture. This appears fine on the screen but when I take the picture the resulting jpg is corrupted (horizontal lines).

As a starting point I used Mark Murphy's Camera/Picture [example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Picture) which exhibits the same issue on the G2.

> The camera paramaters:
>
> preview size: 800x480
>
> picture format: JPEG

Both parameters are supported according to the `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` and `getSupportedPictureFormats()`

The Nexus One, which has the same size screen, works correctly with the same parameters.

The G2 works correctly when setting the preview size to 640x480

My question: Has anyone else run into this issue before (corrupted image despite using supported settings)? How frequent is it? How did you work around it?

Comment: I do not presently have a G2 and therefore cannot answer this question -- sorry!

Comment: @CommonsWare But you havnt seen this issue on other devices? I'm hoping its not common and the upcoming Android 2.3 update fixes it.

Comment: "But you havnt seen this issue on other devices?" -- nope.

Answer (score 0):

So far I had the same issue and now I manage to fix mine using

```
setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
```

Camera parameter settings.

Just recently found out that the camera default picture output was YUV. That's is why it shows perfectly on preview but once the picture is taken you would get a green or pink or corrupted image output.
These are the ImageFormat values which camera might support.

```
JPEG = 256;
NV16 = 16;
NV21 = 17;
RAW10 = 37;
RAW_SENSOR = 32;
RGB_565 = 4;
UNKNOWN = 0;
YUV_420_888 = 35;
YUY2 = 20;
YV12 = 842094169;
```

So other than the supported size, on some cases we might need to check the PictureFormat as well.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlHFH.png

These are just sample images taken using ImageFormat YUV and thus saving it as JPEG compression.

But in any case that you don't want to change the ImageFormat and thus keep the settings in YUV format you may need to save the image in this workaround:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
Camera.Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();
YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, parameters.getPreviewFormat(),
                    size.width, size.height, null);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "YuvImage.jpg");
FileOutptStream filecon = new FileOutputStream(file);
image.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), 90,
                    filecon);
```